# How heavy spring Pageable getTotalElements()?

Tags: java, pagination, spring-data-jpa

if I make query

```
  @Query("SELECT t FROM Product t WHERE t.isApproved = true AND t.partnerId = ?1 AND t.categories.status = ?2")
  Page<Product> findAllProducts(String senderId, String status, Pageable pageable);
```

and call method

```
Page<Product> products = findAllProducts...
products.getTotalElements()
```

will it be called `SELECT COUNT(*)` ?

If 1000 users simultaneously call this and my query is 300 000 rows - Will not it lead to a collapse?

Comment: You could enable SQL logging to know. Or you could read the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters. If that leads to a collapse, then the collapse will happen even without the count query. Make sure the query is optimized (database indices, and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invocation of a query method with `Pageable` argument that return `Page` object produces two query:

- the main query, with additional `limit` and `offset` clauses, that retrieve your data
- and the 'count' query.

The ability of the `findAllProducts` invocation (not the `getTotalElements`) to lead to a collapse depends on your query/database [optimization](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/).

If you don't want your method to call count query you can use `Slice` instead of `Page` as the return parameter:

```
Slice<Product> findAllProducts(String senderId, String status, Pageable pageable);
```

In this case additional count query will not be invoked.

See more info in the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters).